# Is the order of inserted rows guaranteed on DbContext.SubmitChanges()

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Given Records table that have auto increment PK

When I add entities to DbContext as following:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
   dbContext.Records.Add(new Record { TypeId = "TYPE1" });
   dbContext.Records.Add(new Record { TypeId = "TYPE2" });
   dbContext.Records.Add(new Record { TypeId = "TYPE3" });
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Then can I count on the fact that records' IDs will be incremented in the same order as I've added entities to DB context?**

I want to know following query returns the records in the same order.

```
var records = dbContext.Records.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(r => e.RecordId).ToList();
```

Entities are defined as following

```
public partial class Record
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
    public decimal RecordId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TypeId))]
    public RecordType Type {get; set;}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Record>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(record => record.Type)
          .WithMany(type => type.Records)
}
```

*Note: I have queries where I need to get the events in the same order as I have inserted them. I have timestamp, but if the records are produced in the single transaction, I need additional order by.

Comment: I wouldn't, in a multiuser environment especially. There is no need to count on that. Primary keys are meant to uniquely define a row in a table. They don't need to be in order nor they need to be sequential.

Comment: what has multi user environment to do with it? I care only about the order of the records in my context, I don't mind if there are other records inserted between them.

Comment: I got that you want the identities as 1,2,... in order. I wouldn't rely but it does. I don't understand why would someone should rely on the order, maybe you can explain it.

Comment: If you really want to be sure the PK increments in the order you're expecting, I think you'd be safest handling each insert in it's own transaction. If multiple inserts come in under a single transaction, you're at the mercy of the SQL engine's decisions about what order they're committed in.

Comment: If you treat an identity column as an *opaque blob* that happens to fit in a numeric column/variable. All will be well. As soon as you want to care about numeric values, comparing them (except for equality), etc, you're into dangerous territory. If *order matters*, why not *explicitly model* order with another property/column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Knowing the fact, that I can't rely on the order, I will add new column

Comment: Even if it were added in the same order, SQL server itself doesn't guarantee a specific order returning that data unless an order by is used.